# Automated alignment of "tabular" Python code

Tags: python

I have some Python code that looks something like this:

```
rates = {3: [((17500, 99999), Decimal('23425.00'), Decimal('7234.24'))],
         4: [((    0,  3510), Decimal( '4563.00'), Decimal('5234.00')),
             (( 3510, 17500), Decimal('34578.00'), Decimal('3464.50')),
             ((17500, 99999), Decimal('18268.00'), Decimal('5734.66'))],
         5: [((17500, 99999), Decimal('83564.00'), Decimal('3475.60'))]}
```

Note that the decimal values are aligned around the decimal point, while the integers are right-aligned.

Is there some software that can perform this kind of complex alignment in an automated fashion? I'd be interested in anything that gets close, even if it can't match the above exactly.

Comment: [`pprint.pprint`](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) will divide the `dict` up into lines like that, but it won't do any of the number alignment (which is why this is a comment, not an answer). I think you'll have to write something custom to do it.

Comment: IMO, this kind of stuff doesn't ever belong in python code in the first place (it's tabular data, not tabular code).  So even if you "pretty print", it's still ugly anyway.  Load it from a file.

Comment: Ordinarily I would agree with the "doesn't belong in python code" sentiment. The problem is that the structure of the data is entirely ad-hoc, and highly coupled to the code that makes use of the data; and since I'm just implementing rules made up by somebody else (lots of somebody elses, actually), I can't do anything about the ad-hoc nature. Thus any external format is going to have to come close to actual Python code in terms of power, and it's nearly impossible to understand the data without referring to the code that makes use of it.

Comment: If you add a newline right before the first of each pair of Decimal values, your alignment will be good enough to be readable without having to be tabular.  Doing this sort of thing violates the spirit of PEP 8, when it talks about not adding alignment spaces on either side of an assignment (or other) operator.

Comment: Or, alternatively, use SQLite to store the data, so you don't *need* an external format of your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(**NOTE:** I do not consider the following particularly sane.)

For the most part if you just typed out (most editors will help you align your dict and list items) your original code you should get something like this:

```
rates = {3: [((17500, 199999), Decimal('23425.00'), Decimal('7234.245'))],
         4: [((0, 3510), Decimal('4563.00'), Decimal('5234.00')),
             ((3510, 17500), Decimal('34578.00'), Decimal('464.50')),
             ((17500, 99999), Decimal('18268.00'), Decimal('5734.66'))],
         15: [((17500, 99999), Decimal('83564.00'), Decimal('3475.60'))]}
```

(I've made some values longer and some shorter to add a little more quirkiness.)

With the [Tabular](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3464) plugin for Vim, executing the following commands *in order* over the above code (you may want to visually block it) will format the above code in a way that matches your original question:

```
:Tab /^[^[(]*\zs[[(]/l0
:Tab /^[^(]*\zs(/l0
:Tab /(\zs\d\+\s*,/l0r1
:Tab /,\s*\zs\d\+)/l1r0
:Tab /['"]\d*\ze\.\d*['"]/l0r0
```

The operations are:

1. Align the first `[`s and `(`s.
2. Align the first `(`s, this fixes the misalignment from the first operation.
3. Right-align the `(17500,`-like values on `,`.
4. Right-align the `, 99999)`-like values on `,`.
5. Align the `'4563.00'`-like values on `.`.

You could make a mapping for use in normal and visual mode:

```
noremap <leader>ff :Tab /^[^[(]*\zs[[(]/l0<CR>
                  \:Tab /^[^(]*\zs(/l0<CR>
                  \:Tab /(\zs\d\+\s*,/l0r1<CR>
                  \:Tab /,\s*\zs\d\+)/l1r0<CR>
                  \:Tab /['"]\d*\ze\.\d*['"]/l0r0<CR>
```

Final result:

```
rates = {3:  [((17500, 199999), Decimal('23425.00'), Decimal('7234.245'))],
         4:  [((    0,   3510), Decimal( '4563.00'), Decimal('5234.00')),
              (( 3510,  17500), Decimal('34578.00'), Decimal( '464.50')),
              ((17500,  99999), Decimal('18268.00'), Decimal('5734.66'))],
         15: [((17500,  99999), Decimal('83564.00'), Decimal('3475.60'))]}
```

Obviously the effectiveness of these operations depends on the structure and original formatting of the code but hopefully this inspires you.

Answer (score 2):

While the Standard Library `pprint` module will add whitespace to make dictionaries and lists at least look reasonable on the screen, I know of nothing that will, for example, consider the periods in string constants to be significant and add enough whitespace to align them! Unless I am far wrong, you will likely always be doing this kind of alignment in Python by hand.

If you store these values in a separate table file that is plain text, then, of course, you will probably find several editors that would be willing to help you align the decimal points.

Comment: He asked “Is there some software” and I answered “no.” Which, @agf, is indeed an answer.

Comment: I find this answer from a widely knowledgeable person interesting. It brings me information that my little experience didn't have

Comment: @agf _"Is this really an answer?"_ Is this really a comment ?

Comment: @eyquem In my opinion, the lack of answers pointing to a tool serves the same purpose as answers saying "No there isn't one". Answers like Jonathan's show that you don't have to do things like this by hand, that you can program your tools to take care of it for you. Answers like yours show that there is always a solution if you're going to be doing the same thing often enough to make a custom tool worthwhile.

Comment: @agf But all the opinions are in the nature, and in my opinion, _"Explicit is better than implicit"_ is a good mantra.

Comment: @agf --- a mere lack of answers could either mean "There are no solutions" or "Nobody cares about your question."  Though the latter may _imply_ the former, they're pretty different from the asker's point of view.

Comment: @JasonFruit Yes, if it got _no answers_ I'd agree. but it got _three_ answers showing how to do it, one using a tool, which is pretty close to what the OP asked for. I think that is a pretty clear indication of how close to automated you can get -- a better one than either of the "No" answers. Notice I didn't downvote this answer, or the other -- I just expressed my opinion that they didn't add much. If I really thought they were _bad_, I would downvote them.

Comment: @agf --- that's fair enough.  Of course, I couldn't tell whether you voted the answers down or not.

Comment: @JasonFruit Well, neither has any downvotes, which any 1k+ user can check by clicking the score number. But you're right, no reason you would have checked that.

Comment: @agf --- I hadn't realized I could do that.  Neat.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. Management wants a pretty report printed from data in some kind of tabular format.

I didn't want to just do a bunch of print statements with "magic" spaces to fix up the alignment, so I came up with this python function:

```
def column(filename, data, indent=0):
    """This function takes a list of lists and produces columized output"""
    # get the width of the columns
    width = []
    for mylist in data:
        for count, d in enumerate(mylist):
            if count > (len(width)-1):
                width.append(len(str(d)))
            elif len(str(d)) > width[count]:
                width[count] = len(str(d))
    # print the data
    for mylist in data:
        line = '{0:<{indent}}'.format('', indent=indent)    
        for count, d in enumerate(mylist):
            try:
                line = '%s%s' % (line, '{0:{w},} '.format(d, w=width[count]))
            except ValueError, e:
                line = '%s%s' % (line, '{0:{w}} '.format(d, w=width[count]))
        filename.write(line)
        filename.write('\n')
```

It's not perfect, and you'll need to adjust it to produce the output you want. Most specifically, it currently expects a list, because I wanted to pass in a specific order, and dictionaries are not ordered.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a code that do what you want, AFAIU.

It's largely artificial, because it is adapted only to the shape of your precise dictionary.
However, I'm sure it's a basis that could be improved to take account of other specifications, for example several Decimal instances in each tuple.

```
from decimal import Decimal


rates = {3:  [((   500,   999), Decimal('23425.008'), Decimal('   4.24245'))],
         281: [((     0,    10), Decimal( '4563.00' ), Decimal('  34.00'   )),
              ((  3510,   500), Decimal('  578'    ), Decimal(' 464.503'  )),
              ((174500,    19), Decimal('   68.2'  ), Decimal('5734'      ))],
         54:  [(( 93500, 99999), Decimal(' 1564.44' ), Decimal('  75.60'   ))]}



def complex_display(di):
    K,I1,I2,D1B,D1P,D2B,D2P = [],[],[],[],[],[],[]

    for key,val in di.iteritems():
        K.append(len(str(key)))
        for (i,j),d1,d2 in val :
            I1.append(len(str(i)))
            I2.append(len(str(j)))
            d1b,d1p = str(d1).split('.') if '.' in str(d1) else (str(d1),'.')
            d2b,d2p = str(d2).split('.') if '.' in str(d2) else (str(d2),'.')
            D1B.append(len(d1b))
            D1P.append(len(d1p))
            D2B.append(len(d2b))
            D2P.append(len(d2p))

    k   = '%%%dd: [' % max(K)
    fv = "%%s((%%%ds, %%%ds), Decimal('%%%ds.%%-%ds'), Decimal('%%%ds.%%-%ds'))%%s" % (max(I1),max(I2),max(D1B),max(D1P),max(D2B),max(D2P))

    def produce(di):
        for key,val in sorted(di.iteritems()):
            for n,((i,j),d1,d2) in enumerate(val) :
                d1b,d1p = str(d1).split('.') if '.' in str(d1) else (str(d1)[0:-2],"")
                d2b,d2p = str(d2).split('.') if '.' in str(d2) else (str(d2)[0:-2],"")
                yield fv % ('      ' if n else k % key,i,j,d1b,d1p,d2b,d2p,']' if n+1==len(val) else '')

    return '\n'.join(produce(di))
```

result

```
  3: [((   500,   999), Decimal('23425.008'), Decimal('   4.24245'))]
 54: [(( 93500, 99999), Decimal(' 1564.44 '), Decimal('  75.60   '))]
281: [((     0,    10), Decimal(' 4563.00 '), Decimal('  34.00   '))
      ((  3510,   500), Decimal('    5.   '), Decimal(' 464.503  '))
      ((174500,    19), Decimal('   68.2  '), Decimal('  57.     '))]
```

There are not the two characters '{' and '}' , it is a lot of more complexity to add them for a faint result. I let you to complete the code to add them if you want

The result is sorted according the keys.

Comment: Note that the syntax here is unsuitable for Python 2.5, although it works in 2.6 and later:

`decimal.InvalidOperation: Invalid literal for Decimal: ' 1564.44 '`

I assume this can be fixed just by moving the '' around in the template.

Comment: Why do you speak of Python 2.5 ? Python isn't one of these programming languages that are obsessed with retro-compatibility, so I think that pythoneers must evolve

Comment: Debian 5.0 ("lenny") shipped with Python 2.5 as the default version; while we have subsequently migrated to 6.0 ("squeeze") which has Python 2.6 as the default version, I suspect there are still people running 2.5, so I thought I'd mention it since it was fresh in my memory.

Answer (score 0):

It's reasonably simple to write some code to pretty-print your code with whatever alignment you see fit; but you have to tell it what to look for.

When you write it out by hand, you're making a lot of style decisions without thinking much about it, but if you want a program to do the same formatting, you have to make these style decisions explicit. For example, you've decided to align your parentheses vertically, while aligning the list containing 9 elements as if it were actually 3 groups of 3, while completely ignoring the level to which each is nested.

Such an alignment layout really only makes sense with the list you've provided rather than in the general sense, so you're not going to find pre-fab code from someone else to do it like you did. But obviously that doesn't mean you can't do it yourself.

Comment: This might be an answer to some question, but not to the one he asked. He's asking for a software package that does this.

Comment: I just wanted to note that the nesting level is exactly the same throughout the code snippet: each dictionary value is a list of 3-tuples; each 3-tuple consists of a pair of integers, a decimal value, and another decimal value. The only difference is that the lists for 3 and 5 only have one element apiece, while the list for 4 has three elements. I don't entirely blame anyone for not seeing that off the bat, though ;)

Comment: @agf: re-read the last paragraph.

Comment: To give you some idea where I was going with this, http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/ is a step in the direction I would be interested in, but obviously this is much "fancier" than what Tabular.vim can do.

Comment: @tylerl What 9 elements do you allude to , please ?